# Equilibria of a Vector ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $0<\tau<r$. Consider the vector ODE

\begin{align}
\dot{x}=-\tau xy \\
\dot{y}=\tau xy-ry \\
\end{align}

on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$.

Find the equilibria for this ODE and show that the y-axis is an invariant set.

I am having difficulty in solving these ODEs, as I am unsure whether I'm supposed to obtain two separate functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, or a single ODE relating both $x$ and $y$. Additionally, I'd appreciate if anyone could give me any pointers regarding the second portion of the question (showing that it's an invariant set) - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is asking you to find the equilibria for this given ordinary differential equations problem. This does **not** require you to solve the problem given. For the equilibria, you simply want to find the points $(x,y)$ which satisfy:
$$\begin{cases}\dot{x} = 0 \\ \dot{y} = 0 \end{cases}.$$
For the second part of the problem, the $y$-axis is the set:
$$Y = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x =0 \right\}.$$
This is the set that you need to show it is invariant.